# Not able to show permissions dialog on facebook iframe application

Tags: facebook

i am not able to show permissions dialog on facebook iframe application.

can any one help me?

Comment: Well, if you show us what you tried maybe somebody will be able to help you. Add more detail to the question by [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2179445/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Paste Your Code That You Are Using here: in general the code would be:

> FB_RequireFeatures(["Connect"],
>   function() {   
>   FB.init('be13f687478ca790529ba5900f7f1152',
>   'xd_receiver.htm');   
>   FB.ensureInit(function() {    function
>   callback (){ window.location =
>   "http://www.wanamo.com/fb/wmce/index.php?"; };
>     FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog("publish_stream",
>   callback);    });  });

Answer (score 0):

Debjit's method uses the old Javascript SDK. I recommend using the latest SDK. You can learn more here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui

PS. Let me also add that your question is as vague as it can get. It helps to provide more detail. You'll have a better chance of getting a useful response.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Facebook API's available on codeplex.com and use the following code to show the permission page, just add this code in the ASP Page_PreInit Method

```
            base.RequiredPermissions = new List(); 
            base.RequiredPermissions.Add(Facebook.Schema.Enums.ExtendedPermissions.publish_stream); 
            base.RequiredPermissions.Add(Facebook.Schema.Enums.ExtendedPermissions.status_update); 
            base.RequiredPermissions.Add(Facebook.Schema.Enums.ExtendedPermissions.offline_access);

            base.RequireLogin = true;
```

Kind of a duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713353/how-to-do-permission-page-to-facebook-application/3759721#3759721