# How to do “permission page” to facebook application?

Tags: facebook

Please, help me how to do it. When I use another application it seems very simple. It is in every application. I have read documentation and it does not. I make this in "circular" way, but it's working so ugly.

Comment: can you show us some code please, you should read the best practices before making a question.

Comment: but there isn't my code. I know nothing. My code means nothing. It only simple application. I just what know how to do it... :( It's annoying me... I try to do it in many way, but I still can't.

Comment: Which SDK are you using? Which language do you prefer? What permissions do you want. If you want help, you should give us more to work on.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Facebook API's available on codeplex.com and use the following code to show the permission page, just add this code in the Page_PreInit Method

```
base.RequiredPermissions = new List<Facebook.Schema.Enums.ExtendedPermissions>();
base.RequiredPermissions.Add(Facebook.Schema.Enums.ExtendedPermissions.publish_stream);
base.RequiredPermissions.Add(Facebook.Schema.Enums.ExtendedPermissions.status_update);
base.RequiredPermissions.Add(Facebook.Schema.Enums.ExtendedPermissions.offline_access);

base.RequireLogin = true;
```